# How to read a file and check its hash value transparently in Python?

Tags: python, hash, io, sha256

I need to read contents from a file. The sha256 digest is calculated previously. To make sure the file is unchanged, I want to calculate its sha256 digest again while reading, and check it against the previously calculated value. If the values don't match, I should be notified.

What is the pythonic way to do this? I posted working code below but there may be a better way or an existing library doing this.

Answer (score 2):

```
import hashlib
import io

class Sha256File:
    def __init__(self, fo, hashvalue):
        self._fo = fo
        self.hashvalue = hashvalue

    def __enter__(self):
        self._m = hashlib.sha256()
        return self

    def read(self, size=-1):
        b = self._fo.read(size)
        self._m.update(b)
        return b

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        b = self.read()
        if b == b'':
            raise StopIteration
        return b

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_type is None:
            assert self._m.hexdigest() == self.hashvalue
        self._fo.close()

hashvalue = '5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03'

with Sha256File(io.BytesIO(b'hello\n'), hashvalue) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```